# unfortunately k9-email has stopped

Tags: android

I am trying to run K9 email android app in my emulator winXP using eclipse indigo. My project is completely error free but when i am running it in then whenever emulator launches then this error comes. "unfortunately k9-mail has stopped" in emulator.

apk installed in emulator successfully but i am receiving this error in logcat-:

03-10 16:30:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(812): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.fsck.k9.K9: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.fsck.k9.K9" on path: /data/app/com.fsck.k9-1.apk and

unfortunately k9mail has stopped message in emulator.. please do help.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your error.

Comment: You can open the DDMS perspective and check the LogCat for exceptions. Please post this ...

Comment: apk installed in emulator successfully but i am receiving this error in logcat-:  03-10 16:30:23.620: E/AndroidRuntime(812): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.fsck.k9.K9: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.fsck.k9.K9" on path: /data/app/com.fsck.k9-1.apk


and unfortunately k9mail has stopped message in emulator..

please do help.

Comment: yeah, I have exactly the same problem when trying to build and run k9 mail v4.330 using eclipse juno r2 and Android emulator.

Comment: ok, the dex file does not contain com.fsck.*

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the latest Oracle JAVA SE *6* JDK to run Eclipse/to build the apk. Java SE 7 DOES *NOT* work.